# 2.6.35 armel header files?

Tags: linux, utilities, toolchain

Debian does not seem to include a package linux headers 2.6.35-9 for the armel chipset - compiling drivers work, but insmod, and insmod -f is failing with a version mismatch and invalid moduel format.

Could anyone point me to the debian linux headers for 2.6.35-9 please?

Answer (score 0):

No -9 in the snapshots, look here:
http://snapshot.debian.org/binary/linux-headers-2.6.35-trunk-all-armel/